# Where are the white spaces on my website from?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I use WordPress on http://galnanyheter.com/ and for some reason, I get white space between my post (see picture). Have been looking into the code of my theme, and used the Firefox Web Developer add-on but can not find where they come from.

Someone who can help me where the white spaces will come from?[image]

Comment: I think that is a .css matter....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your blocks are probably floated left with no specific height on the floated elements and as the first element is higher than the second it will appear to sit under the other one on the right of the page.

To fix the issue you might choose to set a fixed height on the floated elements ie

```
.entry2 {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    width: 295px;
}
```

Or you may wish to have a clearing element beneath each set of 2 floated elements ie

```
<img style="float:left;"/><img style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"> </div>
```

Comment: Fixed height and clearing element will create a tabular look with lots of unwanted whitespace between some news items - depending on size of course.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `<div>` around your block of `.entry2` articles and set `column-count: 2;` on it. Then remove `width`, `height`, and `float` from `.entry2`. In the demo I set them to `auto !important;` just to override the default stylesheet.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/rBZFn/

HTML:

```html
<div id="sub-content">
```

CSS:

```css
#sub-content {
    column-count: 2;
    column-fill: balance;
    column-gap: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 640px;
}

.entry2 {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float:left` on each news item, which causes this ugly behaviour (as they are of different height, depending on the news content itself).

My solution would be to create two big divs (one for each column), float them left and then stack the news items inside them without floating, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/tdZ9S/2/